# Permission Denial: getHistoricalProcessExitReasons requires android.permission.DUMP

Tags: android

I created a new app in Android Studio and added the code from [here](https://proandroiddev.com/get-app-crash-info-using-gethistoricalprocessexitreasons-b62e8edd369f):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    println("CyberpunkBug: onCreate");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    println("CyberpunkBug: Gettings ActivityManager.");

    // get [ActivityManager]'s instance
    val activityManager = this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager

    println("CyberpunkBug: Build.VERSION.SDK_INT=${Build.VERSION.SDK_INT}");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        val crashLists = activityManager.getHistoricalProcessExitReasons("com.cocos.cyberpunk", 0, 10)
        crashLists.takeIf { crashLists.isNotEmpty() }?.forEach {
            println("CyberpunkBug: Reason: ${it.reason} - Description: ${it.description}")
        }
    }
    else
    {
        println("CyberpunkBug: Build.VERSION.SDK_INT=${Build.VERSION.SDK_INT}, but required ${Build.VERSION_CODES.R}");
    }
}
```

and added `android.permission.DUMP` permission to the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DUMP"/>

    <application
...
```

but the app crashed with the following log:

```
07-14 11:00:04.927 22965 22965 I System.out: CyberpunkBug: Build.VERSION.SDK_INT=31
07-14 11:00:04.927  1127  2384 W ActivityManager: Permission Denial: getHistoricalProcessExitReasons from pid=22965, uid=11105 requires android.permission.DUMP
07-14 11:00:04.928 22965 22965 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-14 11:00:04.929 22965 22965 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 11:00:04.929 22965 22965 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.punk.punkreason, PID: 22965
07-14 11:00:04.929 22965 22965 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.punk.punkreason/com.punk.punkreason.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getHistoricalProcessExitReasons from pid=22965, uid=11105 requires android.permission.DU
```

Android Studio displayed the following warning in the manifest editor:

[image]

How to make this work?